# Crystal Reports Runtime causing AS/400 DB2 Database ID to be disabled intermittently

Tags: crystal-reports, db2-400

I am currently facing an issue and would like to get advice on how to set up a trace to trace all database login connections that are being issued on a Windows Server to our AS400 DB2/400 database. The reason why I want to trace this is that we have a Ripplestone Reporting Server running on the Windows server and we have a set of reports that is being scheduled daily/weekly/monthly via its scheduler. We are using this ID "MISKrystal" to access the database using the iSeries Access ODBC Driver, DISDRP Connection.

Intermittently, the AS/400 side would disable the MISKrystal database ID being used to run the Crystal Reports due to an invalid password being sent from the Windows server. But the only way that the users can access the reports for viewing or scheduling is via the Ripplestone platform, where all the reports are connected using the established DISDRP Connection.

It is becoming a frequent issue, as previously it occurred only once every few months, and now it's happening almost every day or two.

I hope that someone here can point me in the right direction.

Cheers,
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have an AS/400. This isn't mere semantics; searching the web for AS/400-based information might return wildly obsolete information.

One way to find out where invalid passwords are coming from (on the IBM i side) is by way of the security audit journal QAUDJRN. The OS will audit security events when system value QAUDLVL (or QAUDLVL2) has a *AUTFAIL entry. Once the system has auditing turned on, CPYAUDJRNE 'PW' will allow you to copy the password failure events into a table where any query tool will let you explore the contents.

Another mechanism is DSPLOG LOG(QHST) ... MSGID(CPF2234) which filters out the invalid password attempts. Filtering on CPF1393 will show the 'profile disabled' events.

Either of these will tell you if (for example) an end user is trying to crack the password from a green screen (ie not from the Ripplestone machine).

[Using the IBM i security audit journal](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=i-using-security-audit-journal)

Comment: Dear Buck, thank you for your assistance, we found out the Ripplestone Server was the source of the disabled id with information that was sent by the IT Side with the screenshots showing *AUTHFAIL event which shows 3 consecutive failed logon with 2 mins across 3 separate ports.  I'm setting up a trace from the windows side to see what application/program that is triggering the failed login while cross referencing the AS/400 logs on the timing the logon got locked.